# Moving a table (within a table) without using margins and div's

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to create a HTML email and I want to position a nested `table` and move it to the top of the parent `table` (nested `table` will be about `10px` below the parent `table`).

Normally `margins` and `div`'s would be my go to solution, but clients such as Outlook do not support `margins` and div's are always a pain for emails.

Is there a way to achieve this without the above?

If so, how?

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
  <table bgcolor="#F1F3F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#f1f3f2;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
          <!--------->
          <!-- TOP -->
          <!--------->
          <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px; background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/header-image.png);" width="692" height="400">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <!-- TD for whole top section -->
                <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding:25px 28px; border: 1px solid red;">
                  <!--------------------->
                  <!-- LOGO AND SOCIAL -->
                  <!--------------------->
                  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <!-- THIS TABLE NEEDS MOVING UP -->
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                          <a href="http://www.techdata.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img alt="Precise.TV" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/logo.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff"></a>
                        </td>
                        <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                          <!--YouTube -->
                          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/youtube-icon.png"></a>
                          <!--Twitter -->
                          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/twitter-icon.png"></a>
                          <!--LinkedIn -->
                          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/linkedin-icon.png"></a>
                          <!--Facebook -->
                          <a href=""><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/facebook-icon.png"></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <!----------------->
                      <!-- HEADER TEXT -->
                      <!----------------->
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:50px;">
                          <!-- PADDING-->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px; color: #fff; font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-align: center; font-size: 26px;">

                          THIS MONTHS' SHAREABLE<br> MOMENTS FROM PRECISE.TV

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
          </table>
</body>
```

For perspective, the text "this month's..." should sit about 10px on top of the red line.

**Edit**:

What it looks like now:

[image]

**How I want it to look:**

[image]

**How I achieved the above**: With `<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin-top:-170px;">` But I cannot use `margin-top:-170px;` since margins are not supported by email clients.

Also marked in the code which table needs moving up.

Comment: you can use `<br>` tag for margin for mailing supports.

Comment: Can you please clearly mark within the code the actual nested table that needs to be moved?

Comment: @zer00ne done :)

Comment: Why are you worried about how it will look in Outlook? It's never going to work in 2007-2010, 2013, 2016 anyway. You can't use background images the way you're coding this and have them work in Outlook. Use spacer tables to increase the height between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add `valign="top"` attribute to the external `td`:

```
<!-- TD for whole top section -->
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding:25px 28px; border: 1px solid red;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would place a table with two rows. First row with text and the second with another smaller width table, with a red background, centered.

Below is a piece of code that you should be able to work with.

```html
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000">
    <tr>
    <td style="color: #fff; font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-align: center; font-size: 26px;"> THIS MONTHS' SHAREABLE<br> MOMENTS FROM PRECISE.TV </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ff0000" height="3" style="height:3px; line-height:0px; font-size:0px;"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use `<br>` tag before the text "THIS MONTHS"
2. You can add extra row `<tr> <td>` combination before the row with the text

PS
I noticed that `td` element is missing `colspan="2"` here

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-top:50px;">
        <!-- PADDING-->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: <br> makes the nested table move down. I need the nested table to move up?